# Can we use analog input pins as a parameter of analogWrite() for PWM?

Tags: arduino-nano, atmega328

```c++
int led = A1;

void setup() {
   pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  analogWrite(led, 188.7);
  delay(100);
  analogWrite(led ,0);
  delay(100);
}
```

Like this and it works! I mean I am getting the exact voltage as calculated while mapping 5V between 0-255

Comment: you say it works ... so what is your question?

Comment: analogWrite doesn't take float value. the second parameter is int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Nano, only the pins D3, D5, D6, D9, D10 and D11 are PWM-capable.
If you try to `analogWrite()` to any other pin, you will get either
0 V (if you write any value less than 128) or 5 V (for any
other value).

If you get 3.7 V when 5 V is expected, that's because either
your power supply is too weak, or you are putting too a heavy load on
the pin.

Comment: How do I use the analog IO pins for giving an analog output on the Nano?

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu: You don't. The nano cannot give analog output, only PWM.

Comment: PWM output works for my case. But does this mean that the analog pins of an Arduino Nano can only take input and not give an output at all?

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu: The analog pins can provide output, but only logic (either `LOW` or `HIGH`) output.

Comment: Exactly :). How do we do that? Can you point me to an answer that talks of the same?

Comment: @AaronJohnSabu: Like any other logical output: `pinMode(A0, OUTPUT); digitalWrite(A0, HIGH);`